# Bug in the terminal view of Aptana Studio 3 in Windows

Tags: windows, terminal, aptana

Im using Aptana Studio 3 in Windows 7 for a while. It was working well until one day the terminal view has a bug. When a new terminal was opened it was blank  so that I can not type any thin there.

Is there anyone who has been experienced in the same issue. Could you help me to fix this bug. I tried to re-install the software but the terminal still blank.

Best regards,

Comment: solved it. Window -> Preferences -> Team -> Git. At Git Executable, select "...\Git\bin\git.exe"

Comment: Hung Ta, the StackOverflow community encourages people to answer their own questions. If you submit an answer to your question, you will have an opportunity for your answer to be upvoted.

Comment: I have the same probelm and that doesn't solve it for me. I already had git.exe setup in there. My terminal will simply not show anything at all. It used to be useful to see FTP commands in progress, for example. Now it sucks :(

Answer (score -1):

You can restart the pc, it's sometimes work when I restart my computer in Windows 7, but I don´t know that happend.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).